# How to minimize S3 reads when duplicating all incoming data into a DB and also into another location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have devices sending images to an S3. I need to get the metadata from the S3 and put it in a DB, then copy the image into an Azure Blob Storage Container.

All in all this means 2 reads per item:
1) Lambda reads metadata from S3 to put into DB
2) Lambda reads image from S3 to put into Storage Container

Is it possible to get both the Metadata *and* Key with a single boto3 call?

Better yet, is it possible to force the S3 to send the image and metadata as an event to the Lambda? The images are only 20Kb or so, and the metadata is 800 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 sends key to lambda as an event. You cannot make it send the metadata or the object itself. However, the Boto3 [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) method lets you get both streaming data and metadata using a single call.

So you can use event to trigger the lambda with a key then use get_object to perform both operations.